upgrade of Postgres 12.3 /Timescaledb 2.5.1 , very large database of 30TB to PG 16.2 /timescaledb 2.14
We have a very large Postgres database on version 12.3 with timescaledb version 2.5.1.
Size of db ~30 TB
**# of entries in _timescaledb_internal = ~1.7 million. (chunks for historical data).
**# of tables ~8000 **
We tried pg_dump, it doesn't complete in ~24+ hrs, it gets stuck in reading the catalog information.
We tried pg_upgrade from Pg 12.3 to PG 16.2 takes for ever and ends up failing for different reasons every time.
We want to upgrade to latest Postgres version 16.x with timescaledb version 2.14 or later.
What options are best to achieve for such large database ?

failing for different reasons every time doesn't sound right, although I'm not experienced with timescale. One thing you will have to make sure is that the timescale extension is compatible across versions.

Check the manual and if help is needed, share the details about how you're migrating and what exact commands you use and what error messages you get. See https://docs.timescale.com/migrate/latest/

Richard Huston -- I did had a different versions for Timescaledb, as the there is no common version compatible between PG 12.3 and 16.2.  Other option is to upgrade to Version 14 first , then upgrade timescaledb to compatible version , and later to PG 16.x    in all my trails, my upgrades with pg_upgrades failed after 24 hours of operations.

Frank Heinekens -- good document, thank you!, will explore this option.  alternative option,  pg_dump schema only from source/apply to target, then copy out and copy in data in parallel. I can get downtime over the weekends.
